# Asymmetrical Order Effects in Within Subject Design?

Tags: repeated-measures, experiment-design, counterbalancing

I am currently running a study with two groups (control and current psy. disorder). All participants have three conversations, are videotaped and watch the videos of their interactions afterwards, two times. While watching the video, I assess my dependent variable. The tree conversations are the three levels of the within-subject factor. It starts with a neutral conversation, followed by a medium emotional conversation and a strongly emotional conversation.

Now we are considering, to counterbalance the order in which participants watch their videos to prevent learning and fatigue effects. However, I assume that the effect of for example the highly emotional video on any subsequent video is higher than all other combinations.

It is not possible, to run a between subject design. Are there any other options I am not aware of? Perhaps just asking participants how tired they are and how comfortable they feel with the tool?